# How to Handle requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.7

I'm a new user of python. I don't know why but requests always throws an InvalidURL exception:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.google.es/')
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 380, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/url.py", line 392, in parse_url
    return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: https://www.google.es/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 459, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 382, in prepare_url
    raise InvalidURL(*e.args)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: https://www.google.es/
```

This error is independent of the url I give. How do I handle this?

The version of Python is 3.7.7 and 2.23.0 for requests.

Best regards.

Comment: try `r = requests.request('GET','https://www.google.es/')`

Comment: @InfinityTM, I tried with 'GET' as first parameter but the exception was: requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: GET

Comment: Works for me. Please post a __proper__ [mcve]. NB: you may want to make sure that at this point of your code `requests` is really what you expect (just add a `print(requests)` before the call and check your have).

Comment: its the issue with urllib3

Comment: try installing requests v2.21.0

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, this is the minimal example. I only wrote those two sentences in a python console. Printing requests: `<module 'requests' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py'>`

Comment: did u try with requests v2.21.0?

Comment: @InfinityTM I downgraded to the version 2.21.0 and now it works!! Thank you to both of you! I was searching on Google and I dind't find any problem with the packages...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You faced Error due to the New version of `urllib3` (some users tends to face this issue).

The error is not due to `requests` but issue is rather in `urllib3` (new ver) that gets installed when installing `requests 2.21.0+`.
To avoid this either try updating `urllib3`:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade urllib3
```

or install the `requests v2.21.0`:

```
pip uninstall requests # to remove current version
pip install requests==2.21.0
```

- Just downgrade it to `v2.21.0` version

Answer (score 1):

See if you have a hidden character in your URL.

I've wasted tons of time and that was the problem..
this can happen when you copy-paste the URL from somewhere.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @tomer-cohen but it was a problem with the version of urllib3 for me as it was noticed in the previous comment.

Comment: sure, just added this because this was my problem, and I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

it's happen sometimes when the URL is not the valid one. I have this error and after hours found that I have a small spaces between each / on the URL...
so I suggest to write the URL again on requests.get for no get this mistake..