# Constant Error Trying to Use Proxy to Request IP via httpbin.org

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I've been looking around trying to find a solution, but nothing has worked. I have this code:

```
import requests, re
import time


proxies = {
    'http': 'http://:user:pass@proxy_ip:port',
    'https': 'https://:user:pass@proxy_ip:port'
    }

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

I'm getting this error:
`requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))`

I have tried rewriting with urllib as per this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763028/python-3-urllib-http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required?newreg=7f667dae3c8d4938a8017fe79ca7a208)

I have tried adding authentication arguments to the request as per this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862492/python-proxy-error-with-requests-library/8862633#8862633)

I have tried upgrading and or downgrading my requests library as per this post and a few other related posts: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076294/how-to-handle-requests-exceptions-invalidurl-failed-to-parse-in-python)

I have tried adding all headers from the request and that also does nothing.

I am using a static proxy from IPRoyal's proxy service and have double checked to be sure that HTTPS requests are supported for the proxy I paid for.

Any and all help is appreciated, please let me know if any further information is needed and I will try to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer that worked

You need to remove the colon from proxy URL, the redundant one is before the `user`.

#### Another possibility (first answer)

I'm virtually sure that all problem is you've reached the limit of requests and the vendor forbids you to send more. You can test it with `curl`:

```sh
curl -x <YOUR_PROXY_URL> https://httpbin.org/
```

I'm pretty sure you'll have the same `407` error.

If you don't have `curl` or don't know what it is, you can just set your proxy to your browser and see that error as well.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case. The plan I purchased allows me access to the proxy for 30 days with no specified data limits. I also purchased the proxy today so I don't think the error is in the provider. I set my proxy to my browser and have no problem browsing the web either.

Comment: One more idea. Do you try to run your code with proxy URL of `https://:user:pass@proxy_ip:port`? The colon before the `user` — you also use it? Try without it.

Comment: Huh, funny. Those vendors are so funny with HTTP error codes :) I'll add this to my answer.